# How do I change the value of the object's keys depending on the condition in ES6/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

How do I Change the value of the object's keys depending on the condition.
What is the best way to structure and code this?

**Data**

```
const newData = {
  id: 111,
  name: "ewfwef",
  description: "Hello",
  step: 0
};
```

**Code**

```
.then((res)) => {
    switch(res.data.status) {
        case 'data_added': {
           step = 1;
           break;
        }
        case 'product_added': {
           step = 2;
           break;
        }
        case 'consumer_added': {
            step = 3;
            break;
         }
         case 'water_added': {
            step = 4;
            break;
         }
         case 'things_added': {
            step = 5;
            break;
         }
         case 'funky_added': {
            step = 6;
            break;
         }
        default: {
           step = 1;
           break;
        }
     }

    const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));
}
```

**Conditions**

```
step value should be replace based on this condition:

'data_added'    = 1
'product_added' = 2
'consumer_added' = 3
'water_added'   = 4
'things_added' = 5
'funky_added'  = 6
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
  {
    key: id,
    value: 111
  }, 
  {
    key: name,
    value: 'ewfef'
  },
  {
    key: description,
    value: 'Hello'
  },
  {
    key: step,
    value: 2
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the relation between res.data , steps and newData

Comment: @vaira. `res.data.status` is the status I get from the API. Depending on the `status`, `step` value is dependent on that

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your trying to manage some complicated state. Since you are using React, why not use a reducer?

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Depending on your use case, you might also find the context module pattern interesting. Coupled with a well-written reducer and actions, it could make your stateful logic reusable and at the same time provide a natural place for you to do these updates to your state using actions and the flux pattern.
You can check out an example of the context module pattern in action here:

https://github.com/ashkan-pm/react-context-module-pattern

I also suggest you check out some blog posts by Kent C. Dodds on this:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/the-state-reducer-pattern-with-react-hooks
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use an object for mapping the status to step:

```
var stepMap = {
    "data_added": 1,
    "product_added": 2,
    "consumer_added": 3,
    "water_added": 4,
    "things_added": 5,
    "funky_added": 6
}
```

And then, use it this way,

```
.then((res)) => {
    const status = res.data.status;
    if (stepMap[status]) { //checks if the response status is part of our map
      newData.step = stepMap[status];
    }

    const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));
    console.log(data);
  }):
```

Comment: Pls check my question. I've put expected output.  Where is my `const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));` ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Just had to add your code at the end after my code

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood : you want to update newData.step to set it to your res.data.status ?

Since your cases are well known, there is how I would do it :

```js
const STEPS = {
    'data_added' : 1,
    'product_added' : 2,
    'consumer_added' : 3,
    'water_added' : 4,
    'things_added' : 5,
    'funky_added' : 6
};

const newData = {
  id: 111,
  name: "ewfwef",
  description: "Hello",
  step: 0
};

/*...*/.then((res)) => {
    newData.step = STEPS[data.res.status];
    
    const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));

});
```

What i don't understand is this line : `const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));`

What you do there is listing newData keys, then returning an array of key/value pairs of each of it's properties. Is that part of your problem ?

In that cas, you may want to replace the step attribute only in this key/value pair array for the step attribute. So, then you should do something like this :

```js
/*...*/.then((res)) => {
    const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => {
        if(key === 'step') return { key, value : STEPS[data.res.status] };
        else return { key, value: newData[key] };
    );

});
```

Comment: `const data = Object.keys(newData).map((key) => ({ key, value: newData[key] }));` should be the `EXPECTED OUTPUT`

Comment: @Joseph There is something very unclear with your question. You asked for "How do I Change the value of the object's keys depending on the condition." My first exemple address this point. My answer provide you exactly what you want. If you want your output to be this, just add your line following my first example. An SO answer doesn't have to be copy/pasted to your code, but to help you to understand what you have to do to achieve your goal. If this answer doesn't suits your needs, maybe it's because you don't ask your question properly.